# Is there a good drop-in replacement for Java's JEditorPane?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I'm not happy with the rendering of HTML by Swing's JEditorPane. In particular bullets for unordered lists are hideous. Customising the rendering seems extremely difficult. Therefore I'm looking for a replacement with better HTML rendering.

Does this exist? (I asked Google, and found nothing except a promising dead link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that I looked at extensively a while back - and there are many options - however I nearly ended up using http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp, but then the project was cancelled so I can't tell you how it all turned out...

Comment: Cobra works well for my needs. I wish the jar was a little smaller though.

Answer (score 2):

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/05/24/html-pt1.html

Answer (score 0):

Cobra did the trick. Almost a drop-in replacement for JEditorPane, with very nice HTML rendering. One complaint: it's a big jar to add to my little application.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SwingBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/swingbox/).

SwingBox is a Java Swing component that allows displaying the (X)HTML documents including the CSS support. It is designed as a JEditorPane replacement with considerably better rendering results. SwingBox is pure Java and it is using the CSSBox rendering engine for rendering the documents.